# What kind of pump/attachment do I need for this? (picture)

Tags: pump, valves

I am having trouble identifying what tools I need to pump these tires.

We bought some kind of kit that came with multiple attachments and none of them worked. Wondering if something is missing?

All I've ever used before is a presta valve so I am not too well versed in this stuff. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: That sure looks like a schraeder valve to me. You're sure the pump head is set up correctly?

Comment: It's regular schraedder valve. What exactly the problem? The pump do not attaches to valve? Or after pumping the air is runs out?

Comment: Aaand of course, I meant to write Presta. But now I know it's a schraeder, so thanks!

Comment: I know that there are attachments from schrader pumps to presta valves, but I never seen a vise versa attachment.

Comment: The vice versa case practically never occurs - typically you have a schrader pump (everyone has one, for their car or most foot pumps for pumping up balls and stuff and most modern cycling pumps do both) and want to pump something with presta (so you get a presta to schrader adapter), but Silca 2220 is one adapter that does the reverse case (scrhader to presta).

Comment: That is a bog-standard Schrader valve.  If you have a standard chuck for a car valve it will fit.  But, since the tire is deflated, you need to press the tire in with your thumb on the back side of the valve to force the valve out while you fit the chuck to it.

Comment: Possible reasons for not inflating when pumping include having a hole in the inner tube, which is easy and cheap to replace, as well the previous suggestion of ensuring the pump head is properly attached to the valve pushing from the other side to ensure it's properly seated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regular Schrader valve like you will find on many car tires.
Your pump (if it is a bike pump) should have something to pump this up.

If in doubt, head to your local service station and try their car pump. 
Alternatively, hit up a bike store, they should be able to get air in that for you!

Comment: Using a car pump on a bike is dangerous - car pumps are designed to deliver large volumes of air relative to a bike tire (given how big car tires are), and can't necessarily control pressures around what some tires should be run at. But pretty much anyone who has kids should have a schrader valve pump since they're typically used with a needle adapter to pump up balls and stuff.

Comment: @Batman very good point, I had not thought of that - I always manage to just gently squeeze the trigger to get less air at once.